# (QT) 3D surface appears flat on Z axe. How to enlarge the space between each point of an axe?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to plot a 3D surface with QT as in this tutorial [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html).

Hence I have plotted a surface such that the Z axe is between 0.40 and 0.60 with 20 points (The Z axe is like that 0.40, 0.41, 0.42,..., 0.59, 0.60).

The problem is that there is no enough space between each Z points **then the surface appears flat (like a 2D graph - Image below the points are "mixed up")**.

Is there a function (in QValue3DAxis Class for example) for spreading/enlarging the Z axe ? (by a scale coefficient for example).

(Same question with other words) **How to enlarge the space between each point of an axe ?**

Edit : the min max of the range are well set between 0.40 and 0.60 and my code is like very similar of [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html).

[image]